# On-click and on-change events are not triggered sequentially when ajax call is made in one method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input fields and a submit button in a form. Each input fields have *`onchange`* event handler and the button have *`onclick`* event handler functions.

This is the sample dummy form for reference.

```
<style>
    div {
        margin: 15px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    function inputchange() {
        alert("Input change triggered");
    }

    function buttonclick() {
        alert("Button click triggered");
    }
</script>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="buttonclick()" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" onchange="inputchange()" id="input1" placeholder="Input 1" />
    <input type="text" onchange="inputchange()" id="input2" placeholder="Input 2" />
    <input type="text" onchange="inputchange()" id="input3" placeholder="Input 3" />
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/navinchinnasamy/z3vq2n65/12/

When the input value is changed and still the cursor is in that input and the button is clicked means both `onchange` and `onclick` events were fired.

If an ajax call is made in `inputchange()` method then `buttonclick()` method does not get called. Ajax success will not affect the button, only the values of input fields will be modified and updated.

Comment: can you try and explain your problem better? or give an example of what the desired outcome is.

Comment: My desired outcome should be `onclick` event triggered after `onchange` event when I modify the input field and click the button without moving focus from the input. It happens when there is no ajax call in `inputchange()` but if I put an ajax call into this method then `buttonclicked()` does not get called after `inputchange()`. I need `buttonclicked` should be called after update some values in the server on `inputchange()` method through ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change alert in *change* event handler to console.log or wrap both alerts in setTimeout.

```js
const
bind = (el, t, l) => el.addEventListener (t, l, true),
change = ev => setTimeout (
  () => alert (`${ev.target.name}.${ev.type} ${ev.target.value}`),
  200
),
click = ev => setTimeout (
  () => alert (`${ev.target.name} ${ev.type} ${form1.text1.value}`),
  200
)

bind (form1.button1, 'click', click)
bind (form1.text1, 'change', change)
```

```html
<form name="form1">
    <input name="text1" />
    <input name="button1" type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The *click* event will fired after *mousedown*, *focus* and *mouseup* events fired on the same object.

When you change value of text1 and click button1 then events occur in the following order:

1. button1.*mousedown*,
2. button1.*focus*,
3. input1.*blur*
4. input1.*change*
5. button1.*mouseup*
6. button1.*click*

Note that button1 must be in focus before *mouseup* event occurs. But when you call alert inside *change* event handler then button1 loose focus and *mouseup* event will not fired, so *click* event on button1 will not fired too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and it helps me understand how the events are occurring in sequence and the priority of them. The `alert` in the fiddle is to just for example only, my real time problem have an ajax call there to update the input box value in server. In that case the button click event is not happened. If I use either `mousedown` or `focus` event of button instead of `click` event it may solve my problem.